# how to bind button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")
root.geometry("505x500")
root.resizable(0,0)

Blank = tk.PhotoImage(file='Blank.png')
X = tk.PhotoImage(file='X.png')
O = tk.PhotoImage(file='O.png')

def configB(event):
    print('hello')

btn1 = tk.Button(root,image=Blank)
btn1.place(x=0,y=0)

btn2 = ttk.Button(image=Blank)
btn2.place(x=165,y=0)
btn3 = ttk.Button(image=Blank)
btn3.place(x=330,y=0)
btn4 = ttk.Button(image=Blank)
btn4.place(x=0,y=165)
btn5 = ttk.Button(image=Blank)
btn5.place(x=165,y=165)
btn6 = ttk.Button(image=Blank)
btn6.place(x=330,y=165)
btn7 = ttk.Button(image=Blank)
btn7.place(x=0,y=330)
btn8 = ttk.Button(image=Blank)
btn8.place(x=165,y=330)
btn9 = ttk.Button(image=Blank)
btn9.place(x=330,y=330)

btn1.bind('<Return>',configB)

root.mainloop()
```

i want to bind btn1 and i want it to work when i press enter but nothing happens when i press enter as per my code it should print hello .
please help thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you binding to the buttons? Why not just pass in the `command` attribute?

Comment: You would generally want a key binding applied to the window itself.  Applied to a button, it wouldn't trigger unless that button already had the keyboard focus.

Comment: place() should not be used in this way. It has its uses but I would argue for general widget placement it is not a good choice. Use grid() or pack(). That said you can simply add a `command` to your button.

Comment: `command` is triggered only when the button is clicked and pressing return while the button is selected is not same as giving a command option. But usually the case where we require these are in login forms where the user would enter username and password and hit enter and proceeds, then you need to `bind` to the entry widgets and not the buttons, as to get focus to buttons you will have to 'tab' to it.

Answer (score 2):

As @jasonharper said it will work only if button is focused

```
btn1.focus()
btn1.bind('<Return>', configB)
```

and if you click other button then it will not work again

so better bind to main winodw

```
root.bind('<Return>', configB)
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: lower_case_names

def config_b(event):
    print('hello')

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text='1')
btn1.pack()

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text='2')
btn1.pack()

#btn1.focus()
#btn1.bind('<Return>', config_b)

root.bind('<Return>', config_b)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick answer to this question.

Buttons must be bound so as to duplicate (as close as possible) normal button behaviour.

This includes changing button relief and colors, then restoring button.

Finally it has to execute the button command.

The following example does this for two buttons.

1. 'button' responds to Mouse 'Button-3'
2. 'buttonX' responds to Key 'Return'

```py
import tkinter as tk

def working():
    print("Working...")

def actionPress(event):
    event.widget.config(
        relief = "sunken",
        background = "red",
        foreground = "yellow")

def actionRelease(event):
    event.widget.config(
        relief = "raised",
        background = "SystemButtonFace",
        foreground = "SystemButtonText")
    # activate buttons' command on release
    event.widget.invoke()


window = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(window, text = "press", command = working)
button.pack()

buttonX = tk.Button(window, text = "pressX", command = working)
buttonX.pack()

# bind returns unique ID
boundP = button.bind("<ButtonPress-3>", actionPress)
boundR = button.bind("<ButtonRelease-3>", actionRelease)

boundXP = buttonX.bind("<KeyPress-Return>", actionPress)
boundXR = buttonX.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", actionRelease)

# This is how to unbind (if necessary)
# button.unbind(""<ButtonPress-3>", boundP)
# button.unbind(""<ButtonRelease-3>", boundR)
# buttonX.unbind(""<KeyPress-Return>", boundXP)
# buttonX.unbind(""<KeyRelease-Return>", boundXR)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need parameter in `configB` method.  Also don't need bind for button1. I also add command in button1 widget. Comment out in line 36 `#btn1.bind('<Return>',configB)`

```
def configB():
    print('hello')

btn1 = tk.Button(root, command=configB)
```

Result:

[image]

Btw, I don't have `png` image.