# Mimic activebackground with bind

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like a function so that when clicking with the right mouse button (`'<Button-3>'`), the button would execute an animation like `activebackground = 'Red'`.

Is it possible?

```
import tkinter as tk


def Blink_red_when_right_click(event):
    # Blink red when right click
    # I do not know how to do this
    pass


window = tk.Tk()
window.resizable(False, False)
window.configure(bg='#4F4F4F')
window.geometry('400x160+800+230')

button = tk.Button(window, bg='#00FA9A', text='Blink red when right 
click')
button.bind('<Button-3>', Blink_red_when_right_click)
button.pack(pady=30)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes it is. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, sometimes. But I couldn't.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You need to use a binding on your button. Here is a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67972436/how-to-bind-button-in-tkinter

Comment: I edited the code for better understanding.
Nothing I've tried has worked.
What I need is for the Blink_red_when_right_click function to make the button blink red as if it were the activebackground.

Sorry for the incomplete information, I'm learning to program as a hobby.

Comment: If you want button to flash then here is link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73792818/flashing-button-that-stops-flashing-when-pressed-in-tkinter-without-using-flash

Comment: @Derek, thanks for sharing this solution.
Added a lot of knowledge.

Comment: Soluction should be posted as answers not as and edit of the questions.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import tkinter as tk


def Blink_red_when_right_click(event):
    button.configure(background='red')
    window.after(100, lambda: 
    button.configure(background='#00FA9A'))
    # Blink red when right click


window = tk.Tk()
window.resizable(False, False)
window.configure(bg='#4F4F4F')
window.geometry('400x160+800+230')

button = tk.Button(window, bg='#00FA9A', text='Blink red when right 
click')
button.bind('<Button-3>', lambda event: 
Blink_red_when_right_click(event))
button.pack(pady=30)

window.mainloop()
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74174798/3) to the question [Mimic activebackground with bind [SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74174798/mimic-activebackground-with-bind-solved) by the OP [Renato Gomes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20174814/renato-gomes) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>